# I can't connect to assets & link path

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, laravel-5

*I want to link path assets and other page. pls help me, how I should to do ???*

**Problems !**

Now, I can connect to http://yoseigi.com/night/ ,but I can't connect assets inside.

[skeleton]/laravelfiles/app/view/index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.ace.login')

@section('pagecontent')
    @{{ app_path() = }} <?php echo $path = app_path(); ?>
@stop
```

[skeleton]/laravelfiles/app/view/layouts/ace/login.blade.php (Code Assets Path)

```
{{-- Bootstrap --}}
{{ HTML::style('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
{{ HTML::style('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css') }}
```

Style Sheet -->  "Index.php" ?????

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://yoseigi.com/night/Index.php/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://yoseigi.com/night/Index.php/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
```

yoseigi.com/dashboard

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://yoseigi.com/night/dashboard"
```

**Routes**

[skeleton]/laravelfiles/app/routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return View::make('index');
});
Route::get('dashboard', function() {
    return View::make('dashboard');
});
```

**Directory**

```
yoseigi.com
|--httpdocs
    |--night
        |--assets
            |--ace
               |--css
               |--js
            |--bootstrap
               |--css
               |--js
        |--laravelfiles
            |--app
               |--config
                    |--app.php
                    |--view.php
               |--views
                    |--layouts
                        |--login.blade.php
                    |--dashboard.blade.php
                    |--index.blade.php
               |--routes.php
            |--bootstrap
               |--autoload.php
               |--paths.php
               |--start.php
        |--packages
        |--.htaccess
        |--index.php
```

**htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    #RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Config**

[skeleton]/index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/laravelfiles/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravelfiles/bootstrap/start.php';
```

[skeleton]/laravelfiles/bootstrap/paths.php

```
'app' => __DIR__.'/../app',
'public' => __DIR__.'/../..',
'base' => __DIR__.'/..',
'storage' => __DIR__.'/../app/storage',
```

[skeleton]/laravelfiles/app/config/view.php

```
'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../views'),
'pagination' => 'pagination::slider-3',
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the HTML facade, try using the asset() helper.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```